# How to speed up this cross-correlation function in Python 3.5 by numba or using other tricks?

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.5, numba, cross-correlation

```
"""
x is generally a numpy array having 1728000 points, y is a numpy array of 100 points 
"""  

import bottleneck as bn  
def xcorr(x,y):  
    N=len(x)  
    M=len(y)  
    meany=bn.nanmean(y)  
    stdy=bn.nanstd(np.asarray(y))  
    tmp=rolling_window(x,M)  
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):  
        c=bn.nansum((y-meany)*(tmp-np.reshape(bn.nanmean(tmp,-1),
        (N-M+1,1))),-1)/(M*bn.nanstd(tmp,-1)*stdy)  
        c[M*bn.nanstd(tmp,-1)*stdy == 0] = 0  
        return c
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please tell us more - what speed are you currently getting? What is your requirement?

Comment: this function is called many times in a Python script and I am looking at the fastest way to compute c.

Comment: Fastest question are hard to answer. I would guess you're already getting a speed of <100ms - is that correct? Have you tried comparing it to numba?

Comment: Charlie, your speed estimation is ok. Bottleneck helps a lot but I was looking to improve velocity if possible. Checked Numba for examples without spending a lot of time. However, I need to read the documentation carefully before trying. Have you an idea about Numba applied to this function call ?

Comment: I haven't used Numba but my guess is that it will be hard to get this less than say 10ms with Python unless you are able to "batch" and increase you number of points per call. I'll be interested to see what others think.

Comment: Tried Numba 0.25 version coupled with np110py35_0. Got some errors: ./test_numba.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vuan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numba/bytecode.py", line 249, in _fetch_opcode
    info = BYTECODE_TABLE[opcode]
KeyError: 143

Comment: If you need help running numba that would be a different question. Please try asking again if that's what you want.